# Likelihood ratio tests in Growth Mixture Modelling with large sample sizes

Tags: likelihood-ratio, large-data, mplus, growth-mixture-model

I recently conducted Growth Mixture Modelling in a Structural Equation Modelling framework using a sample of n~300,000. I found that for any number of trajectories I fitted, the Vuong-Lo-Mendell-Rubin likelihood ratio test (VLMR) and Lo-Mendell-Rubin adjusted likelihood ratio test (ALMR) produced p-values <0.001. I used `Mplus` for these analyses.

My understanding is that, much like Chi-square p-values, these likelihood ratio test p-values are sensitive to large sample sizes. Is anyone able to confirm this? Any reading/citations would be gratefully received.

Please do let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would say you are in an enviable situation, as most applications of growth mixture models (GMMs) have sample sizes that are not ideal (e.g., see Bauer 2007 for more info).

This being said, your understanding is correct: both the Vuong-Lo-Mendell-Rubin likelihood ratio test (VLMR) and the Lo-Mendell-Rubin adjusted likelihood ratio test (ALMR) can be sensitive to large sample sizes, similar to the Chi-square test. This sensitivity arises because as the sample size increases, even minor deviations from the null hypothesis can produce statistically significant results.

Regarding the literature on model fit of GMMs, Nylund, Asparouhov, & Muthén (2007) is the most cited reference on the topic. In their article, they conclude that the bootstrap likelihood ratio test (BLRT) is the best method for choosing the number of trajectories (or "classes" more generally). However, I'm sure you would run into similar issues given your large sample size (not to mention that the BLRT is very computationally intensive).

Personally, I would recommend using some sort of cross-validation (CV) approach to select the optimal number of trajectories. See Grimm, Mazza, & Davoudzadeh (2017), He & Fan (2019), and Whittaker & Miller (2021) for more information on CV applied to mixture modeling.

**References**

Bauer, D. J. (2007). Observations on the use of growth mixture models in psychological research. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 42(4), 757-786.

Grimm, K. J., Mazza, G. L., & Davoudzadeh, P. (2017). Model selection in finite mixture models: A k-fold cross-validation approach. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 24(2), 246-256.

He, J., & Fan, X. (2019). Evaluating the performance of the k-fold cross-validation approach for model selection in growth mixture modeling. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 26(1), 66-79.

Nylund, K. L., Asparouhov, T., & Muthén, B. O. (2007). Deciding on the number of classes in latent class analysis and growth mixture modeling: A Monte Carlo simulation study. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 14(4), 535-569.

Whittaker, T. A., & Miller, J. E. (2021). Exploring the enumeration accuracy of cross-validation indices in latent class analysis. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 28(3), 376-390.